# How to deploy streamlit on standalone server

Tags: python, apache, tornado

I am able to configure Apache for streamlit using Configuring Apache 2.4 for proxy…

But to serve I have to do streamlit run myapp.py

Is there better way to serve the streamlit APP???

Comment: User supervisrod to run the app in background. http://supervisord.org/running.html

Comment: I have same problem just like you. My streamlit project is done, Apache configuration is finished, and port forwarding is also finished so index.html can be run from outside of my local server. But I can't figure out how to do 'streamlit run app.py'

Comment: @2asy Streamlit is using tornado server. So, Can't deploy via apache.

Comment: @user13744439 Thanks for comment. I've seen streamlit deployment guide in streamlit community, and one of the option was apache. So I thought I can deploy streamlit on apache(https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-deployment-guide-wiki/5099). If I can't deploy it in apache, is there another way to depoly it on my local computer?

Comment: @2asy If its Windows machine..may be using docker....if Linux...you can use Docker or supervisord